# Animations with Swift

Tags: animation, swift

I'm trying to make an app with animation designed with multimple images like frames. I use UIImage.animationImages, UIImages.animationDuration and UIImage.animationRepeatCount, but this only show an animation with specified list of images in a determinate time, but I need to stop much seconds in one image like in another images of the image list. For example, in Android we have the option to make an xml setting images and the time of duration of each image, and this is what I need in Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom UIImageView like this for example.

```
class CustomImageView : UIImageView
{
    var animationDurations : [Float] = []
    private var isAnimating = false
    private var animationCount = 0
    override func startAnimating() {
        if let images = animationImages
        {
            if images.count == countElements(animationDurations)
            {
                animationCount = 0
                isAnimating = true
                self.changeImages(0)
            }
        }
    }

    override func stopAnimating() {
        isAnimating = false
    }

    func changeImages(currentIndex : Int)
    {
        if currentIndex == 0 {
            animationCount += 1
        }
        if animationCount > self.animationRepeatCount && self.animationRepeatCount > 0
        {
            isAnimating = false
        }
        if !isAnimating{
            return
        }
        if let images = animationImages
        {
            let nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.count
            self.image = images[currentIndex] as? UIImage

            let floatDelay = animationDurations[currentIndex] * Float(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(floatDelay))

            dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.changeImages(nextIndex)
            })
        }
    }

}
```

It can be used like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView : CustomImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        imageView = CustomImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 60))
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2

        let images : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "2.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "4.png")!]
        let imageDuration : [Float] = [1.0,2.0,0.6]

        imageView.animationImages = images
        imageView.animationDurations = imageDuration
        imageView.startAnimating()

    }
}
```

Comment: I try these making an external class to reuse, but when I try to run in simulator, it returns an error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=2,...)" in line: imageView.animationDurations = imageDuration

Comment: Are you adding it as an IBoutlet and using interface builder?

Comment: Yes, the only change betweem your code and mine is that my UIView is IBOutlet from storyboard and not hardcoded

Comment: Did you set class as customimageview inside the interface builder

Comment: You have to set the the class in the uiimageview u placed in the interface builder